# Strange behavior of gotoandplay on mouse over with three level nested swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a swf-A that loads and plays the swf-B using gotoAndPlay whenever a MOUSE_OVER event is fired on a certain object. When hovering a mouse over the object the animation of swf-B is played and everything worked just fine.

```
object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,handleMouseEvent);

[Embed(source = "B.swf")]
public static var EmbedSwf:Class;
[Bindable]public var _swf:MovieClipLoaderAsset = new EmbedSwf();

private function handleMouseEvent(e:Event):void{
  MovieClip(Loader(_swf.getChildAt(0)).content).gotoAndPlay("animation_start");
}
```

However, when I embeded the swf-A into another swf-C, the animation of swf-B was not played when a mouse is over swf-B but played after mouse was put over swf-B and moved out. (An appearing timing is strange)

I have confirmed that the mouse events were fired properly. I also set mouseEnabled of swf-C to false and set swf-A to use the same ApplicationDomain as swf-C.

Due to the fact that the problem did not happen when swf-A is not embeded into swf-C, I assumed that the problem may be from embeding. Did I miss something when embeded the swf-A into the swf-C?

This is my first time asking on this site. If there is something not enough in my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It appears a cause of the problem was that a flex version of the wrapper swf-C(flex-4.6) was higher than the wrapped swf-A(flex-3.4.1.10084A) and it caused the strange behavior.

I have downgraded the flex version of the wrapper swf-C and everything worked out.